# Constant reference std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector, stdvector

How can I have a reference to a specific element in a std::vector?

The easy way should be to store it as the index of the element (I am using a size_t variable).

The problem I have is the possibility of inserting an element before the current, making the stored value incorrect.

Comment: Maybe `std::vector` isn't the right container for your needs. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Fred Larson @templatetypedef I don't want to point the element itself, I want to point to its position. What I am creating is a algorithm for using in boolean operations in polygons, I need to find the intersection points between two polygons and know wich one is in the same position in the other polygon, so I can jump from one polygon to the other correctly. I think about std::list, but I don't know if it allows me to do such things.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a very good way to keep track of a single element inside the `vector` by a pointer, reference, or index.  In particular:

1. If you insert a new element into the `vector`, it may cause all outstanding references to the `vector`'s elements to be invalidated if an internal reallocation occurs.  Insertions can happen either by calling `insert`, `reserve`, `push_back`, or `assign` (plus perhaps a few others).  This could cause the reference to refer to an invalid object, resulting in undefined behavior if the reference is used.
2. If you remove an element from the `vector`, then the reference may no longer point at the same element.  Accessing the reference may result in you referring to the wrong object.

If you really must hold a reference to an element in a `vector`, one option would be to have the `vector` store (smart) pointers to objects instead of the objects themselves.  That way, you can store a copy of that pointer elsewhere and no matter what happens in the `vector`, the pointer should still be valid.  This is really the Fundamental Theorem of Software Engineering in practice - adding another layer of indirection can solve most problems.

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable solution is to have your vector be a vector of pointers and just remember your pointer.

Otherwise you can't maintain a reference because, as you mentioned, the vector might move elements around.

Answer (score 0):

Use a vector that contains auto pointers, i.e. `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<YOUR_ELEMENT_TYPE>>` if you are using c++0x.